# clase mysqli no reconocida por php8

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, windows, php8

Instale manualmente mysql, junto a mysqlworkbench, php8 y apache, el problema es que al estar trabajando en un proyecto a la hora de ejecutar una conexion a mi bd, la aplicacion me daba el error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli" not found in ...

estuve investigando, al parecer en windows, en versiones superiores a php 5 ya tiene activado por default la libreria, aun asi configure en php.ini la extension, estaba comentada, una vez habilitandola seguia igual, al iniciar el ejecutable php.exe para abrir la consola, me daba un error el cual decia que no se podia cargar la boblioteca dinamica, al parecer intentaba cargar la libreria desde "C:/php" la cual en mi pc es "c:/php8", tras especificar la ruta completa de donde se encuentra el archivo .dll, el php.exe se ejecuta mostrando la linea de comandos, pero al probar la pagina web, me sigue mostrando el mismo error.

Mi SO es Windows 10, mi php es version 8

[image: PhP.INI CON RUTA SETEADA]

Comment: ¿El archivo existe en esa ruta? ¿Escribe esto en consola y verifica si estás revisando el archivo `php.ini` correcto: `php --ini`  ahí te deberá decír que archivo ini se está cargando.

Comment: asi es amigo, no se por que, pero al instalar el php8 por dafault la carpeta que creo con todo su contenido se llama php8, no php, justo verifique que si estuviera el .dll y si se encuentra en el directorio

Comment: mmm me parece que esta mal configurado, las extensiones tienen un ruta de configuración en xampp quedaría así: https://i.imgur.com/xpraThR.png me avisas si te sirve para agregarlo como respuesta.

Comment: otra consulta es necesario usar MySqli por que no usas PDO??? https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: Ya di con la respuesta, al parecer tenia que configurar tambien la ruta de la carpeta y del php.ini en las configuraciones avanzadas de windows para que pudiera acceder, muchisimas gracia spor tu tiempo y tus respuestas amigo! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer el problema aqui fue lo siguiente: aparte de habilitar la extension en el php.ini se deben de agregar las rutas debidas en la configuracion de sistema de windows, la ruta es la siguiente: inicio>panel de control>sistema>opciones avanzadas>variables del entorno, una vez dentro en el apartado de variables del sistema se tiene que hacer doble clic en la entrada "PATH" y agregar la carpeta de php, despues, crear una variable totalmente nueva en las variables de sistema, la cual se debe de llamar "PHPRC" y como valor la ruta del rchivo php.ini, una vez hecho esto reiniciamos y TA DA! :) espero le ayude a alguien en el futuro gracias a todos!

https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath

Answer (score 0):

estuve revisando el problema y en mi caso desde windows utilizando VScode con la extension phpserver es necesario tener configurado el item PHP Config Path con la ultima version de php donde se incluye el archivo php.ini con la extensión mysql.dll habilitada (sin ; al inicio de la linea ).

Comment: Asegúrate que al responder una pregunta no sea texto lineal, agrega fragmentos de código o imágenes (solo en el caso necesario), con esto, ayudamos a comprender mejor lo que quieres decir y la solución que brindas.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).